# Blender export video format to Da Vinci Resolve

Tags: export, video, file-format, encoding

I'm currently working on an ads project, and i would like to export my shots so i can edit them in Da Vinci Resolve.

I would like to know what format do i need to use in Blender so i can imported my shots in DVR?

(I would avoid using PNGs sequence or other image sequences).

Thank you.

Best regards, Samih.

Comment: **OpenEXR** is the way to go, if you want production quality. There is neither any appropriate container format nor any production codec to choose (meaning dnxhd 10bit or prores).